# Just like my metal

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

You're going to laugh, but I need your help again.

With a deadline to hit I pulled an all nighter and despite copious amounts of coffee, I fell asleep shortly after midnight.

I awoke to what could be described as Pollock masterpiece. Mugs were strewn across my desk and my long labour of work was ruined. Deep stains enveloped my papers and the desk was even worse.

I crossed my fingers and attempted to try and salvage something. Over to the *coffee table* I went, trio of scraps in hand.

After a moment I noticed the coffee had reacted to my inks, maybe I can recover something after all!

**Can you please help figure out what I was working on last night?**

Scrap #1

> [image]

Scrap #2

> [image]

Scrap #3

> [image]

Thank you in advance for any assistance you may provide.

Comment: Is the answer just supposed to be your chemistry homework or something? It's unclear what the scope of the puzzle is.

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper To give more information on the 'work' would be difficult without a massive giveaway. There is a clear answer for the question, I assure you it's not as vague as it seems.

Comment: Great artwork! What did you use to draw these?

Comment: Thanks @Clangorous Chimera. It's mostly edited photos but it was done in Clip Studio Paint (AKA Manga Studio).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By taking all three sets of markings and overlaying them, we see:

> [image]
>
>   a caffeine molecule!
>
>  [image]

Comment: Awesome that was faster than expected!

Comment: You wouldn't care to actually add the overlaid image to you answer?

Comment: @BmyGuest - I traced the three images in red, green, and blue. That first image is the overlaid tracings.